# How to listen for changes on formik field with nested values?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

What I want to do is when certain field from formik change, do something.

e.g.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // do something
}, [values.someField])
```

But if I have a dynamic name value ( from props ), that can be anything (e.g. `field.name`, `field[0].otherField`, `level1.level2.level3`) how can I make this effect?

```
const MyComponent = ({ name }) => {
    const { values } = useFormikContext()

    useEffect(() => {
        // do something
    }, [/* what to put here? */]) 

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Could you share the exact scenario? It is easier to understand the issue with the real input, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figure it out, I need to use `getIn` from `formik`

```
import { useFormikContext, getIn } from `formik`

const MyComponent = ({ name }) => {
    const { values } = useFormikContext()

    const fieldValue = getIn(values, name)

    useEffect(() => {
        // do something when some field in the form changes
    }, [fieldValue]) 

    // ...
}
```